# How to create a docker container to run a TCP server

Tags: docker, nestjs, microservices

I want to run my TCP server in a docker container, so I tried to build an image and started the container. I am not able to connect to it using telnet.

This is the error I got

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This is my docker file

```
FROM node:16.15-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
COPY . /app/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start:prod
```

but it worked fine when I ran the server locally.
I don't want to use the host network in docker, so let's say my server is running on port 3000 inside the container I should be able to bind it to any port on the host. I cannot use docker-compose because my clients and servers may be hosted in different hosts entirely

docker ps output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
dbf747c8a413   test-2    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   39 hours ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   test-3
```

Comment: yes, you can bind any port only if it is available. Can you write the out put of   Docker ps  ? Also run this command and write the out put.   sudo docker logs ContainerID

Comment: I have update question with docker ps and as for logs
"[Nest] 17  - 01/16/2023, 8:04:57 AM     LOG [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +912ms"
It started fine but when I tried to connect to it, I was unable to connect and there are not logs for in docker logs section